# pdf to a docx converter using Tesseract-OCR

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I’m trying to develop a converter that can accurately extract text, tables, alignment, and tab formatting from PDF files, including those written in Bangla Bangladeshi language. Currently, the code I'm using is unable to understand the Bangla Bangladeshi language,

so I'm trying to incorporate **Tesseract-OCR** to improve the output. However, I'm still facing issues with getting the desired output.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import os
from pdf2docx import Converter
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import pytesseract


current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

input = os.path.join(current_path, "input.pdf")
output = os.path.join(current_path)


def pdf_to_docx_and_extract_text(path, save_path):
    """Convert PDF file to DOCX file and extract Bangla text using pytesseract"""

    if Path(path).is_file() and (
        Path(path).suffix == ".pdf" or Path(path).suffix == ".PDF"
    ):
        try:
            docx_file = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0] + ".docx"
            cv = Converter(path)
            cv.convert(f"{save_path}/{docx_file}", start=0, end=None)
            cv.close()

            # Extract Bangla text from the converted DOCX file
            docx_path = f"{save_path}/{docx_file}"
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
                docx_path, lang="ben"
            )  # Specify 'ben' for Bangla language
            print("Extracted Bangla text:")
            print(text)

        except Exception as ex:
            mb.showerror("ERROR", f"File has not been decrypted")
    else:
        mb.showerror("INFO", "File not found!")


pdf_to_docx_and_extract_text(input, output)
```

I'm seeking assistance to enhance it for extracting text, tables, alignment, and tab formatting from PDF files written in **Bangla Bangladeshi** language.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is.  Can you correctly extract the text from the pdf using tesseract-ocr  or are you experiencing problems in placing the text in the docx file.  Please provide more explicit explanation of what aspect you need help for.

Comment: @itprorh66 experiencing problems in placing the text in the docx file. When pdf2docx converted a docx file it also converted text and table in a docx file but my problem is that my pdf file text is in Bangla Bangladeshi Language and pdf2docx can't give it correctly only OCR can give it correctly. I'm trying to use OCR-generated text in a docx file when pdf2docx converted pdf file.